# Want to be able to create a Teams online meeting in Graph API that links to a Teams Channel

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

Im trying to programmatically create a Teams Meeting in Graph API that has a Teams Channel associated with it and appears in user calendar and sends email to invitee.

Through the UI this would look like this:

[image]

But I can't work out how to do this using Graph API

If I use the Graph API
POST [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{organiser}/events](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/%7Borganiser%7D/events)

and include property in the body  isOnlineMeeting: true

then it does indeed create an online meeting in the calendar, sends the invites etc, but does not create the meeting in the teams channel

If I use the Graph API
POST [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{organiser}/onlinemeetings](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/%7Borganiser%7D/onlinemeetings)

and include the property in the body chatInfo { threadiD:  }

then it creates an online meeting for the channel but unfortunately does not make the meeting appear in any calendar or send an email, so not sure what the point of this is.

I thought maybe I could do it as a 2 stage process, whereby I could create the onlinemeeting first and then reference it in the onlinemeeting : { joinUrl : "" } property, but this seems to be ignored when I set this.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create an event in a team's channel within a single request.

1. First [create an event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-post-events?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) using graph API.
2. You can [send notification message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/conversation-basics?tabs=dotnet#adding-notifications-to-your-message) with Weblink/join URL as a
   deeplink to a channel.

Comment: Thanks, how would you get the bot in 2. to make the recording of the meeting to appear in the teams channel?

Answer (score 0):

I've done some digging and finally was told about this Youtube from Microsoft.

[Considerations for Creating Online Meetings with Micrsosoft Graph](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dv_OPxD7E6o)

Basically the answer to my question above is ... you can't.

Microsoft have decoupled creation of Events in Outlook calendar to to the creation of Online meetings through what Micrsoft are calling the Cloud Communications API (ie. the graph api for online meetings mentioned in my question).

So you can create Online meetings with many features, such as connected to Teams Channels etc, and the purpose of these is that they can be used in a variety of systems like Google Calendar etc and not tied solely to Outlook.

If you want to create Online meetings to appear in Outlook you are stuck with just the events Graph API which is limited in features.

There is no way to associate an Online meeting created through the Cloud Communications API with an Event created through the Event Graph API.

A shame really, as this was what I was hoping to do.